# Compiling node.js v0.10.48 with npm and other tools (Windows 7)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, compilation, windows-7

For various reasons I have no control over I have to compile node.js from source, I can't use official installer (and it has to be v0.10.48).

When I was compiling older releases, running `vcbuild` resulted in bundling `npm` in `Release` folder. However, when I compiled v0.10.48, all I have in this folder now is `node.exe` and `openssl-cli.exe` (well on top of usual `.lib` and `.pdb` files).

How can I ensure that all the related tools (see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/meta/topics/dependencies/#tools) are built with release?

Commandline I'm using:

```
vcbuild.bat release x64 nosign
```

Platform: Windows 7 x64.